# remove react navigation blue line

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to remove blue line when clicked the react navigation icon appeared. How can i remove it ? Also I noticed that when i clicked first icon and after that i clicked last icon 3 icon at middle also rendered( They changed color to orange for a while) can i fix it ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your Top Tabbar `tabBarOptions` following value:

```js
tabBarOptions={{
        indicatorStyle: {
          backgroundColor: null,
        },
      }}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats worked. Can you check my second question? Are there any solution for that ?

Comment: please share the minimum reproducible code of the above app so that I can look into the icon behavior. Or I would suggest posting a new question for it altogether.

Comment: I have tried going through the documentation, but it seems that Transition animation is set by default, I tried setting up transitionConfig prop but they are not working either, I defiantly think that there is some way out of it, have to go through a lot of docs pages and GitHub open issues :)